# Problem creating subreport for Javabeans datasource in iReport 3.7.0

Tags: javabeans, ireport, subreport

I am using iReport 3.7.0. The subreport wizard screen do not show my any Javabean class to select. Please let me know if anybody has encountered this problem and got a solution.

[image]

[image]

Creation of PersonDatasource:

[image]
[image]

Source code for the Javabeans avialable at

> > http://www.brucephillips.name/jasperreports/examplesource.zip

Thanks
Nayn

Comment: Can you be more specific about the PersonDataSource? How is it defined?

Comment: Updated the question. The normal report with javabeans datasource runs fine. While adding subreports, it cribs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created report separatly and added that as a subreport in the main report. I had to tweek the jrxml a little bit and DONE. Subreport with Javabeans works fine now.

```
<subreport>
   <reportElement x="100" y="20" width="355" height="20"/>
   <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{phones})]]>
        </dataSourceExpression>
   <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "report_sub.jasper"]]>
        </subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Comment: However iReport does not behave as expected in the Subreport creation wizard. That bug needs to be resolved.
>> http://jasperforge.org/plugins/mantis/view.php?id=4480